# Merging tables into New table while retaining information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize in advance as the title is not very descriptive.

I have approximately 40+ tables each with the same exact table layout columns, and data save for one column. I would like to take that column which is not the same across all the tables and merge them into one table. Confusing? Let me illustrate..

SRCTbl01:

```
ID  TYPE  COLR1  INSTOCK
-----------------------
1    B     RED    YES
2    B     BLUE   YES
3    P     GREEN  NO
4    B     BLACK  YES
```

SRCTbl02:

```
ID  TYPE  COLR1  INSTOCK
-----------------------
1    B     RED    YES
2    B     BLUE   NO
3    P     GREEN  YES
4    B     BLACK  YES
```

SRCTbl03:

```
ID  TYPE  COLR1  INSTOCK
-----------------------
1    B     RED    YES
2    B     BLUE   NO
3    P     GREEN  NO
4    B     BLACK  NO
```

RESULT: (Type P to be excluded)

```
ID  TYPE  COLR1  SRCTbl01  SRCTbl02  SRCTbl03
----------------------------------------------
1    B     RED    YES       YES       YES
2    B     BLUE   YES       NO        NO
4    B     BLACK  YES       YES       NO
```

And finally after all that I'd like to make the table look something like this:

INSTOCK Table:

```
Customer  RED  BLUE  BLACK
---------------------------
SRCTbl1   YES  YES   YES
SRCTbl2   YES  NO    YES
SRCTbl3   YES  NO    NO
```

I'm not entirely sure whether I can directly manipulate the tables into looking like the final iteration so I thought I should ask how to get it to the first Result as to me it seems simpler.

Thank you for the help, I've spent a full 8 hours on this and have yet to find a way to achieve it so I have come here to ask the experts.

EDIT: To clarify, I have had zero success in achieving the results I illustrated above. I have tried using SELECT .. Union SELECT, and FULL JOINS.

Using this code resulted in duplicates ( I was trying to just get the INSTOCK)

```
SELECT 01.INSTOCK, 02.INSTOCK, 03.INSTOCK
FROM dbo.SRCTbl01 AS 01, dbo.SRCTbl02 AS 02, dbo.SRCTbl03 AS 03
WHERE 01.TYPE='B'
```

I tried very many but this is probably the closest I got.

Comment: You should post your previous attempts of solving the problem otherwise your question will be probably closed as *off-topic*. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"

Comment: Could you clarify - you  don't actually need `RESULT`, right?

Comment: Well the final table I want would be the last table illustrated, but I thought I needed to get to RESULT before being able to get to the final table. I'm trying out the samples given by Raphael and Dan currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like that, all in one :

You first flatten with union, then take the max 'instock' for each color by customer (MAX will work as 'YES' > 'NO')

```
select Customer, MAX(RED) as RED, MAX(BLUE) as BLUE, MAX(BLACK) as BLACK
FROM(
  SELECT 'SRCTbl01' as Customer, 
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'RED' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as RED,
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'BLUE' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as BLUE,
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'BLACK' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as BLACK
  FROM SRCTbl01
  WHERE  Type <> 'P'
UNION
  SELECT 'SRCTbl02' as Customer, 
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'RED' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as RED,
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'BLUE' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as BLUE,
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'BLACK' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as BLACK
  FROM SRCTbl02
  WHERE  Type <> 'P'
UNION
  SELECT 'SRCTbl03' as Customer, 
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'RED' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as RED,
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'BLUE' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as BLUE,
       CASE WHEN COLR1 = 'BLACK' then INSTOCK ELSE 'NO' END as BLACK
  FROM SRCTbl03
  WHERE  Type <> 'P'
) as a
GROUP BY Customer
```

(You just need to add a `CREATE TABLE INSTOCK as <codegiven>`)

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18635/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. For some reason the INSTOCk has been defined as a bit as such I had to use CAST(RED AS tinyint) and change the 'NO' to 0. Its so extremely close to the results! Thank you so much. I'll try to figure out why the column names don't appear and will post the final iteration.

Comment: @HexEDSyght column name does not appear : just use aliases : MAX(RED) as RED, MAX(BLUE) as BLUE, etc. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using UNION and PIVOT, something like this should do what you want (PIVOT should work on SQL Server 2005 and newer):

```
SELECT Customer, [Red], [Blue], [Black]
FROM (
    SELECT 'SRCTbl01' AS Customer, COLR1, INSTOCK FROM SRCTbl01 WHERE Type <> 'P'
    UNION
    SELECT 'SRCTbl02' AS Customer, COLR1, INSTOCK FROM SRCTbl02 WHERE Type <> 'P'
    UNION
    SELECT 'SRCTbl03' AS Customer, COLR1, INSTOCK FROM SRCTbl03 WHERE Type <> 'P'
    /* UNION ... */
) AS SRC
PIVOT (
    MAX(INSTOCK)
    FOR COLR1 IN ([Red], [Blue], [Black])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: PIVOT doesn't want to work on my SQL server for some reason.
I did test your code in SQL Fiddle and it worked perfectly though.

Comment: What is the SQL server version and buildnumber you're using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. It gives me this error.
`Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.`

Comment: What is the compatibility level of your database? In SQL Server Management Studio, you can find out by right-clicking on the database and choosing "Properties". Then it will show the compatibility level under "Options". `PIVOT` only works for compatibility level 100 or higher on SQL Server 2008 and compatibility level 90 or higher on SQL Server 2005: http://blog.ysatech.com/post/2009/07/29/Incorrect-syntax-near-PIVOT-You-may-need-to-set-the-compatibility-level-of-the-current-database-to-a-higher-value-to-enable-this-feature-See-help-for-the-stored-procedure-sp_dbcmptlevel.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much Dan, the compatibility level has been set to 80, SQL Server 2000. Unfortunately the server version has also been set to level 80. Your answer works great when compatibility is 90 or higher, and its more compact, but Raphael's works on my server so I'll select his as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to disturb. Why can't I use Cast within MAX within a Pivot?
Pivot(MAX(CAST(INSTOCK AS tinyint))...)

Comment: @HexEDSyght You can only use aggregation functions inside the PIVOT statement. However, you can just cast INSTOCK in the FROM-part of your query: `SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT CAST(INSTOCK as tinyint) INSTOCK ... ) AS src PIVOT ( MAX(INSTOCK) ... )`